# An inequality and a convex function

Tags: functions, inequality, convex-analysis

I was solving this problem:

If $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are positive real numbers with $abcd=1$, prove
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{a+b+2}+\frac{1}{b+c+2}+\frac{1}{c+d+2}+\frac{1}{d+a+2}\leq 1
\end{equation}

I do the change of variable:
\begin{equation}
  x_1=\frac{1}{a},\quad x_2=\frac{1}{b},\quad x_3=\frac{1}{c},\quad x_4=\frac{1}{d}
  \end{equation}
and the first term is
\begin{equation}
  \frac{1}{a+b+2}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x_1}+\frac{1}{x_2}+2}=\frac{1}{\frac{x_1+1}{x_1}+\frac{x_2+1}{x_2}}
  \end{equation}
Consider the convex function $f(x)=\frac{x+1}{x}$, we have:
\begin{equation}
  f\bigg(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}\bigg)\leq\frac{f\big(x_1\big)+f\big(x_2\big)}{2}
  \end{equation}
this is:
\begin{equation}
  \frac{\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}+1}{\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}}\leq\frac{\frac{x_1+1}{x_1}+\frac{x_2+1}{x_2}}{2}
  \end{equation}
the inverse is:
\begin{equation}
  \frac{1}{\frac{x_1+1}{x_1}+\frac{x_2+1}{x_2}}\leq\frac{x_1+x_2}{2\big(x_1+x_2\big)+4}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{x_1+x_2+2}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+2}
  \end{equation}
If $F(a,b,c,d)$ is the LHS of the inequality to prove, for the rest of terms we do a similar expressions and add, we obtain:
\begin{equation}
  F(a,b,c,d)\leq 2 - F\bigg(\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{b},\frac{1}{c},\frac{1}{d}\bigg)
  \end{equation}
this is:
\begin{equation}
  F(a,b,c,d) + F\bigg(\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{b},\frac{1}{c},\frac{1}{d}\bigg)\leq 2 
  \end{equation}

My question is:
It is possible for positive real numbers $y_1$, $y_2$, $y_3$ and $y_4$ with $y_1y_2y_3y_4=1$ to find $a$, $b$, $c$ i $d$ with $abcd=1$ and
\begin{equation}
  F\big(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4\big)\leq\frac{F(a,b,c,d) + F\Big(\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{b},\frac{1}{c},\frac{1}{d}\Big)}{2}
  \end{equation}

I suspect this is not difficult but I don't progress. If this is proved, the inequality is demostrated.

Comment: See AoPS: [1](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c1068820h2131399p15580230), [2](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1644765p10375752), [3](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h528863p3010730)

Comment: Thanks you! But the convexity question remain unsolved.

Comment: For your final inequality, do you want it the other way around? If no, can you elaborate on why finding such $y_i$ would demonstrate the inequality?